# How do I add a transparent background color to a pop up?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, frontend, popup

I am building a pop up and I am trying to make my background transparent when the pop up loads. When I click a button, the background should become transparent but instead in my case, it goes completely dark. I have tried troubleshooting for a while but I have failed. I have shared the code I am running below;

VUE FILE:

```
       <div id="app">
            <button class="button" @click="showModal=true">Show row</button>
            <transition name="fade" appear>
              <div class="modal-overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="showModal=false">
              </div>
            </transition>
        </div>
```

CSS FILE:

```css
#app {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.button {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  background: #4ea046;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #CC2E5D, #FF5858);

  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;

  box-shadow: 3px, 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;

  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
}

.modal-overlay {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 98;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);` is a black background with alpha value of `0.2`. Why not just remove that?

Comment: when I remove it and click the button, there is no change at all ie the page background doesn't change at all

Comment: I don't see any problems. Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? What if you remove the `<transition>`?

Comment: @DecadeMoon when I run the code there(jsfiddle.net), it works as expected. but when I try in my code, it just brings a dark screen

Comment: Well then something else is happening on your end that we don't know about and cannot help you with unless it is reproducible for us too. Can you try a different browser?

Comment: yes, I have tried another browser but still ran into the same issue.

Comment: Are you using single file components? If so, are your CSS styles scoped?